# How to replace one column with another using data.table?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a dataframe:

```
ID      value1   value2
1        f        a
2        k        p
3        c        j
```

I want to replace values in column value1 with values from value2 and remove column value2. So desired result is:

```
ID      value1   
1        a        
2        p        
3        j
```

I need to do it with data.table. And i need to do it with function, not recreating dataframe from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `data.table` you can do :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, value1:=value2][, value2:=NULL]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, c("value1", "value2") := .(value2, NULL)]
```

Or with `setnames()`

```
df[, value1 := NULL]
setnames(df, "value2", "value1")
```

Data

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:3, value1 = c("f", "k", "c"), value2 = c("a", "p", "j")
)
```

Comment: Your first approach is cool! Upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below

```
> setDT(df)[, .(ID, value1 = value2)]
   ID value1
1:  1      a
2:  2      p
3:  3      j
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(ID = 1:3, value1 = c("f", "k", "c"), value2 = c("a", 
"p", "j")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   select(ID, value1 = value2)
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, value1 = c("f", "k", "c"), value2 = c("a", 
"p", "j")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```